# Ember, how to reuse same "partial" for "index" and for "show"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, partials, htmlbars

This is the simplified version of my situation:

```
<!-- app/templates/charts/index.hbs -->
{{#each model as |chart|}}
  {{partial "charts/chart"}}
{{/each}}

<!-- app/templates/charts/show.hbs -->
{{partial "charts/chart"}}

<!-- app/templates/charts/-chart.hbs -->  
{{chart.title}}
```

The partial `-chart.hbs` works well for the `index` template but not for the `show`, because for the `show` the chart is into the variable `model`.

How can I fix this so I can reuse the same partial for `index` and for `show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a case for [Ember Components](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), as far as I can see it.

Let me explain a bit, to get you started.

Components are bits of reusable code with some structure attached. That means a component will have:

- a template (*.hbs file)
- a component JS file

You can move your partial's template into a component (let's name it **chart**), like this:

1. Move the code as it is into a new component template.
2. Use variables/objects inside your template, as you probably do now
3. Instead of rendering it with `{{partial "charts/chart"}}` do `{{chart componentObject=localObject}}`
4. This will pass an external object (be it a model or whatever) to a component's context, as follows:

_

```
// context code:
<h1>{{localobject.title}}</h1>

{{chart componentObject=localObject}}

// component code
<p>{{componentObject.author}}</p>
```

_

You mileage may vary. Please feel free to comment and/or improve my answer :-)